# Is it optional to use value for input in Controlled component in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and wanted to learn how to properly use forms. Then I found out that there is something called Controlled forms so I wrote this code:

```
<input
  name='name'
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Is it optional to use "value" attribute since we already add the input data to state with `onChange`? Is it true that value is needed just to ensure that the input data is properly added to the state? Just to be confident?

Comment: Yes. value={this.state.name} is optional. You can get the value of input through only onChange.

Comment: No it is not, try `{this.state.name||''}` You cannot set value to undefined and not setting the value gives you an **uncontrolled input**

Comment: But if you don't use it, It won't show what you typed in the input box.

Comment: @AlokMali It will but it's an uncontrolled input so you can never reset it from code (like setting it to an empty value)

Comment: @HMR, pls can you create an answer for the question and if possible clearly saying what problems we face if we use <input
                        name='name'
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>

Comment: @HMR, just omitting value={this.state.name}

Comment: @qwww See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: @HMR, please can you at least clarify " it's an uncontrolled input so you can never reset it from code (like setting it to an empty value"

Comment: @qwww Added answer, with uncontrolled input you can never set it's value. The only way to change it is when the user types something in the input. In the example you can type something in the uncontrolled input to set the value of the controlled input but you can never do it the other way around unless you provide a `value` property to the uncontrolled input, but when you do that it's no longer uncontrolled (controlled inputs have a `value` property (or checked if they're radio/check). With controlled inputs you should never set it's value to undefined.

Comment: I'm looking for a satisfying answer to this question too. @HMR If you need to reset occasionnaly you can just use a ref to the html element, no ? It feels like it would be more efficient performance wise. As each time you type something in the input, the state will change an re-render the component (for nothing, because the html has already written what you typed on the screen before "value" has been written). No  ?

Answer (score 0):

A [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) can be set by state or props because you give it a value property. If you do not provide an onChange to a controlled component then you cannot change it's value because the `value` property comes from state or props.

An [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) does not have a `value` property so it manages it's own value, when the user types something in a textbox then it'll show that text. You can add onChange to an uncontrolled component but you can't reset it (because it doesn't have a value property).

```js
const App = () => {
  const [controlled, setControlled] = React.useState('');
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    e => setControlled(e.target.value),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          contolled (can also set value with uncontrolled)
          <input
            type="text"
            value={controlled}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          contolled but no onChange, just follows other inputs
          <input type="text" value={controlled} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          uncontrolled (can never set it's value)
          <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```